# Cómo obtener el contenido de una etiqueta link con javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero mostrar el css de mi página pero al intentar hacerlo de las formas tradicionales no me muestra nada, en su lugar me entrega un mensaje que según dice es un archivo HTML

```js
// EJECUTO
var link = document.querySelector(".link");

document.write(link);

// RESPUESTA
// [object HTMLLinkElement]

// SEGUNDO EJEMPLO
// document.write(link.innerText);

// RESPUESTA
// NINGUNA
```

```html
<link href="#" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" class="link">
```

Comment: ¿puede que te sirva [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244094/get-stylesheet-content-from-head)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener el `css` del `link`, lee el css al que apunta del atributo `href`, realiza un `fetch` del archivo y muéstralo en tu página. Quedaría:

```js
let link = document.querySelector("link");
fetch(link.href)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => document.write(text))
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```